# Can't pass a function as an argument Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

i'm studing matlab and I get some problem with a code.

First, I've created f1.m:

```
    function y = f1(x)
       y = exp(x) - pi;
    end
```

Then, I built a code to find the roots by bisector method:

```
function [root, err, n] = bissect(f, a, b, errMax)


    m = (a+b)/2;
    err = (b-a)/2;
    n = 0;
    

while err > errMax
    
    
    if f(a)*f(m) > 0
        a = m;
    else
        b = m;
    end
    
    m = (a+b)/2;
    err = (b-a)/2;
    n = n + 1;
end

root = m;
end
```

But, when i run

```
>> [r,err,n] = bissect(@f1, 1, 2, 0.1);
```

it returns:

> Warning: Subscript indices must be integer values.
>
> In C:\matlabR12\work\Codigo\bissect.m at line 12
>
> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in ==> C:\matlabR12\work\Codigo\bissect.m
>
> On line 12  ==>         if f(a)*f(m) > 0

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Matlab R12

Comment: Do you have a variable `f1` in your workspace? `clear f1` should solve this.

Comment: Complementing Cris' comment: [Function Precedence Order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html)